# Subtract years from current date

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am not able to subtract required number of years from current date.
If we can add years to current date like:

```
DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)
```

Why is there no such method to subtract years?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because:

```
DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
```

However, if you really want a SubtractYears method, you can always use

```
public static class DateExtensions
{
    public static DateTime SubtractYears(this DateTime dateTime, int years)
    {
        return dateTime.AddYears(-years);
    }
}
```

and to test it:

```
[TestCase(0)]
[TestCase(1)]
[TestCase(2)]
[TestCase(10)]
[TestCase(2012)]
public void SubtractYearsWorks(int i)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    Assert.AreEqual(now.AddYears(-i), now.SubtractYears(i));
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's quite a nice feature of C# syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need separate method for that. Just use `AddYears` with `-1`:

```
DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
```

According to MSDN [`DateTime.AddYears` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addyears.aspx):

> A number of years. **The value parameter can be negative or positive.**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
```